# How do you separate unit tests from integration tests in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I've been using Visual Studio 2008 Test projects to store my tests.  Lately I've realized that a lot of my unit tests are in fact integration tests because they rely on external sources (e.g. file system, SQL server, registry).

My question is, what is a good approach to separating out integration tests from unit tests?

Ideally I want only the unit tests to show up in the Test View, because I run them frequently during development.  The integration tests on the other hand I don't want in the Test View because I will only run them infrequently, e.g. when I'm about to make a build drop.

Answer (score 17):

Keep them in separate projects, and keep the integration testing projects out of your day-to-day Visual Studio solutions.

When you wish to run the integration tests, you can use a different solution that includes them. If you don't want to wait for a second instance of VS to load, you can run them from the command-line.

Answer (score 14):

I put them in a separate project named IntegrationTests or something similar.

EDIT:

With Test View you can create lists & filter them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182452.aspx

And then run them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182470.aspx

Comment: This was what I was thinking at first, but how do you prevent it from showing up in Test View?

Comment: Filter them out or use TestDriven.Net

Comment: Unloading integration tests project might work well enough too.