# What project for Integration Tests in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, integration-testing

I have a pretty simple question: What kind of project should I create for `Integration Tests` in Visual Studio? The only proposed project type under `Test` tab in `Visual C#` is `Unit Test Project`, but it's not integration test, so I'm not sure

This is what I read, but couldn't find an answer :

[Integration Testing In Visual Studio With Different Project Types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32060452/integration-testing-in-visual-studio-with-different-project-types)

[How do you separate unit tests from integration tests in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894339/how-do-you-separate-unit-tests-from-integration-tests-in-visual-studio)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the unit test project template. You will create your integration tests in there.

The unit test project is just a template that provisions the necessary dependencies. You could just as easily create an empty project and manually add what it needed.

Comment: Please make sure to avoid using the word "unit": in the new project name